# MVC how to show/display images from database(sql server 2008 r2) by nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display images from database but it appears I able to display the URL name instead of the picture.

Any help please? thanks!

i am using sql server 2008 r2 My datatype in the table for image is `nvarchar` (as I require to use this instead of image):

```
ImageURL1 nvarchar(255)
```

Here's how I create the picture to database. I call it `create.cshtml`

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageURL1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageURL1, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageURL1)
    </div>
```

Here's my display view of my pages (but it seems only able to display the URL LINK instead of the picture).

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActivityTask.activityID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL1)
    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MemoryController",new { id = item.ImageURL1 })" />
    </td>
```

Here's my controller codes

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Memory memory)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {              
            db.Memories.Add(memory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.ActivityTasks, "activityID", "activityID", memory.ActivityID);
        ViewBag.TaskID = new SelectList(db.ActivityTasks, "taskID", "taskID", memory.TaskID);
        ViewBag.ImageURL1 = new SelectList(db.ActivityTasks, "ImageURL1", "ImageURL1", memory.ImageURL1);
        return View(memory);
}
```

and the code I have a hard time figuring out how to call

```
// get image view
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
        Memory memory = db.Memories.Find(id);

        var imagedata = memory.ImageURL1;

       return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than that. All you have to do is reference the image you want.

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Pic.png")
```

Comment: the problem is i have too many images, i need to view them all out, how to i do that?

Comment: Use a forloop maybe?